# Получение указателя на объект

Tags: c++, qt

Использую библиотеку Qt, но это не суть важно в нижеприведённой проблеме. Появилась необходимость, заключающаяся во введении в форму внешней программы текстовой информации — иными словами, имитирование события в сторонней программе. Каким образом возможно заполучить ссылку на этот объект (текстовую форму, в которую, собственно, и нужно и сымитировать ввод символов) во внешней программе? Посредством чего к нему (к этой форме во внешней программе) вообще можно обратиться, **как к ней обратиться**? 
Стоит отметить, что, конечно, код внешней программы неизвестен.

Comment: Никаким. В лучшем случае - удастся получить handle на окно, потом на его элемент и работать через SendMessage/PostMessage. Начните с https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Положим, мы пользуемся Windows. У вас несколько путей:

- Старый добрый WinAPI. Отсылаете `WM_*` сообщения (`WM_SETTEXT`, например), по необходимости внедряетесь в процесс и вытворяете прочие подобные вещи. На виндовые события реагирует большинство программ.
- Более новый Automation. Он поддерживает как старые классические виндовые контролы, так и новомодные GUI фреймворки вроде WPF.

Учтите, что, если авторы программы активно пользуются кастомными контролами и при этом не выставляют наружу средств для управления, то приложение будет для вас сплошным чёрным прямоугольником, в который, как в бездну, можно только отсылать события и надеяться, что не промахнёшься.

Если приложение не полагается на события и не выставляет интерфейсы для автоматизации, то вам повезло ещё меньше.

В целом, зависит от программы.

Для начала можете поробовать воспользоваться AutoHotKey, в котором есть множество средств для управления программами. Если работает в нём — значит, сможете переписать на более привычном для вас языке (если AHK не хватит).